# Relative Path to Files in Playwright

Tags: playwright

I am writing a test that requires mocking of the camera to simulate reading a QR code, for that I use:

```
const browser = await chromium.launch({ 
args: [
 "--allow-file-access-from-files",
 "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
 "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream",
 "--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=path_to_file", //path to file
],
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that the path to the file only seems to work using absolute paths but not relative.

The project has the following structure:

Project Folder->Playwright(where the file is located)->Specs->Special_Cases->My_Test

In the config file there's:

```
 testDir: "./specs"
```

I've tried various relative paths:

`./Filename` assuming it would start in the playwright folder

`./../Filename` assuming it would start in the specs folder

`./../../Filename` assuming it would start in the special cases folder

None of these worked as it the test it says no devices detected (I know the file is able to mock the camera since using the absolute path works).

Is a relative path not able to be used or is the initial current folder somewhere else? I am using playwright in typescript if that's relevant.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the full command you are using to execute this file from cl?

Comment: I am running the tests using the UI mode mostly. But from the command line I'm using

npx playwright test My_Test --headed